# Configuración BD en lectura

Tags: php

Necesito su colaboración, y es que en laravel hay una forma de configurar el archivo **database.php** para que tenga una base de datos de lectura y una base de datos de escritura. Ejemplo en laravel:

```
'mysql' => [
'read' => [
    'host' => [
        '192.168.1.1',
        '196.168.1.2',
    ],
],
'write' => [
    'host' => [
        '196.168.1.3',
    ],
],
'sticky' => true,
'driver' => 'mysql',
'database' => 'database',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
'prefix' => '',
```

],

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo lograr algo similar pero hecho en PHP Nativo para sólo nodo de lectura? Gracias

Comment: Puedes utilizar PDO de Php https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Comment: Para ti ¿qué es "PHP nativo"?. ¿Qué nodo?.

Comment: Duplicado. Pregunta creada 2 veces por el mismo usuario [Configuración database.php para base de datos en lectura](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489004/configuraci%c3%b3n-database-php-para-base-de-datos-en-lectura)